# Подключение intellij idea к локальному git репозиторию

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Я создал свой гит репозиторий, и к примеру для того чтобы запушить или клонировать его использую

> ssh://some.one@127.0.0.1/my_project.git

такой URL. Как привязать его к идеи?

Comment: Checkout и выбрать гит и его адрес. Или VCS / Checkout from / выбрать гит и адрес

Comment: @gil9red это для обычного подключения к гиту! а у меня свой сервер...

Comment: Он на одном пк ?

Comment: Если да укажи путь просто

Comment: @croll да, я указал. но просит ввести или токен, или пароль и логин, ввожу логин, а оно мне "407 proxy autentication required"

Comment: У вас же логин в адресе указан, при подключении скорее всего пароль запрашивает, а вы опять логин вводите.